# Can't get printf to align properly

Tags: java

I'm writing a method to print a table of values that I've precalculated. At the end of the table, I'm printing a line that says

```
Sum of Deposits:   $XXXX.XX
End of Year Total: $XXXX.XX
```

My code for that looks like this:

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.printf("%1$-10s $%2$-10.2f", "Sum of Deposits: ", (monthsToPay * monthDep));
System.out.println("");
System.out.printf("%1$-10s $%2$-10.2f", "End of Year Total: ", allDepTotal);
```

Unfortunately, instead of aligning so that the numbers are on top of each other (proper columns), the padding formatting doesn't seem to be doing anything. I can change it to

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.printf("%1$-10s $%2$-15.2f", "Sum of Deposits: ", (monthsToPay * monthDep));
System.out.println("");
System.out.printf("%1$-10s $%2$-15.2f", "End of Year Total: ", allDepTotal);
```

and the spacing/formatting doesn't change. What am I doing wrong? I've tried everything I could think of for troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.printf("%1$-19s $%2$10.2f", "Sum of Deposits: ", (monthsToPay * monthDep));
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.printf("%1$-19s $%2$10.2f", "End of Year Total: ", allDepTotal);
```

The second literal is 19 characters wide. The - flag means left align and is not what you say you want for the numbers. You may have meant to use +.

I suggest you take a look at [the formatter specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two formats that are key: One for the preceding String and one for the value.

`"%-20.20s"` allows you to format the String as you would want, you would just want to change 20 to the length you want to format the Strings to. The first 20 defines the minimum length of the String as 20; if it does not meet this it will pad the String with spaces. The second 20 defines the maximum length of the String as 20. If it does not meet this, it will truncate the String starting from the right. The '-' in front says to pad the spaces on the right, giving the effect of a left-align.

`"%07.2f` allows you to format the float as you would want. The `.2` says fit to 2 decimal places, padding 0s if required. The "07" part fits the whole part of the number to 4 decimal places. It essentially says the minimum length of the String is 7, but as you have 2 decimal places and a decimal point that means the minimum length of the whole part of the number is 4. The preceding 0 appends 0 if the whole part is less than 1000. This does not put an upper limit, however, but this can be easily achieved by taking the modulus of the float if you want to enforce this limit.

While removing the lower resolution of a number can be acceptable, enforcing an upper limit is not recommended as you lose *very* important information; especially in finance.

```
System.out.printf("%-20.20s $%07.2f", "Sum of Deposits: ", 10.02 % 1000);
System.out.println("");
System.out.printf("%-20.20s $%07.2f", "End of Year Totals: ", 12300.02 % 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign in the format `%2$-10.2f` causes your numbers to be left-aligned.  Changing the width just prints more blanks *after* the numbers and so makes no visual difference.

Just use `%210.2f` instead (without the minus) to obtain right-alignment.  Read all about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).